# Error when passing an input through an object

Tags: java

I created a method makesPerson() which takes input String[] and int[]. It is giving an error when i create an object and give the inputs as array of strings and int.It was working fine when the input were just String and int and not arrays.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int    height;
}


public class TestPerson {

    public void display(Person persons) {
        for (int i=0;i<persons.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(p.name[i]+":"+p.height[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestPerson p1=new TestPerson();

        //This is giving me error
        p1.makePerson({"joe" ,"jhon", "Alex"},{150,160,170});
    }

    public Person[] makePerson(String[] names, int[] hts) {
        Person [] persons = new Person(names.length);

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
            Person p = new Person();

            p.name     = names[i];
            p.height   = hts[i];
            persons[i] = p;
        }

        String str = "";

        for(int i=0;i<persons.length;i++) {
            str += persons[i].height + ": :";
            System.out.println(str);
            display(persons);

            return persons;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: `Person [] persons=new Person(names.length);` it makes no sense

Comment: why the question d/votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method arguments to something like:

```
p1.makePerson(new String[]{"joe" ,"jhon", "Alex"}, new int[]{150,160,170});
```

instead of

```
p1.makePerson({"joe" ,"jhon", "Alex"},{150,160,170});// <- your sending String and ints not Arrays.
```

Also your display method is taking a array of persons not a person. so change it to:

```
public void display(Person[] persons) {
```

And in the `makePerson` method, you declaring array with a wrong way, it should be like:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[names.length];
```

Comment: @ Salah Yeah it pretty much solved the whole error problem.Do we always have to mention this when passing an array as input??

Comment: Yes, Or you could create an array in the normal way like to say `String[] names = new String[3];` then add values like `names[0] = "Joe";` and so on, then pass the `names` as argument like : `p1.makePerson(names, ints);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've made several mistakes, so I've re-written your code:

```
public class TestPerson{

    public void display(Person[] persons)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<persons.length;i++)
        System.out.println(persons[i].name+":"+persons[i].height);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestPerson p1=new TestPerson();
        String[] names = {"Joe" ,"John", "Alex"};
        int[] hts = {150,160,170};
        Person[] persons = p1.makePerson(names,hts);

    }

    public Person[] makePerson(String[] names,int[] hts){
        Person [] persons = new Person[names.length];

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
            Person p= new Person();
            p.name=names[i];
            p.height=hts[i];
            persons[i]=p;
        }


        display(persons);

        return persons;
    }
    public class Person{
        String name;
        int height;

    }
}
```

Now, I believe, it does what you've expected. Your initial error was related to a wrong array initialization during method call.

Output:

```
Joe:150
John:160
Alex:170
```

Answer (score -1):

You should consider adding some safety checks to your loops. Like:

```
public Person[] makePerson(String[] names, int[] hts) {
    if (names.length != hts.length)
        throw new IllegalArguementException("different array sizes");

    final Person[] persons = new Person[names.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        Person p = new Person();

        p.name     = names[i];
        p.height   = hts[i];
        persons[i] = p;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(persons[i].height + ": :");
        display(persons);
    }

    return persons;
}
```